# GET http://localhost:8000/acce/onc/1 404 (Not Found) 1:1

Tags: laravel

** THE ERRORS:
handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined     at chrome-extension://mmnbenehknklpbendgmgngeaignppnbe/c1.js:7:40**
**i have to pass a detail from a table to an form. **

**event blade: from here if i press the accept button ,it should pass the user id to the next page**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class ="info">
    <h1>THE</h1>
    <h2>{{$users[0]->ename}}</h2>

      <p class= "line">
    _________________________________</p><br><br>
      <h2>The Details</h2>
      <p>{{$users[0]->stime}}</p>
      <p>{{$users[0]->etime}}</p>
      <br>
      <h2>{{$users[0]->dis}}</h2>
      <p>The Park</p>
      <p>7, Mahatma Gandhi Rd,Karnataka,560042</p>
      <p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3887.9680899320642!2d77.6174511141303!3d12.973892790854384!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae169ca8334f21%3A0x2f71ab422db4f935!2sThe%20Park%20Bangalore!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1612344904547!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
      </p>     <p class= "line">
    _________________________________</p>
    </div>
    <button class ="accept"><a href='onc/{{$users[0]->id}}'>Accept</button>
    <button class ="doubt">May be</button>
    <button class ="regret">Regret</button>

  </div>
@endsection
```

**accept blade: this contains a form and i need to use the tables details here**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

<form  method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <h2>Event Creation Form</h2>
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
    <label for="name"><i class="fa fa-user"> Name</i></label>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
  <label for="en">Choose a Category:</label><br>
<select name="en" id="en">
  <option value="event">{{$users[0]->ename}}</option>
</div>
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="no" id="no" required/>
    <label for="no"><i class="fa fa-user"> No Of People:</i></label>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"  value="event In" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

**web.php and controller**

```
Route::get('onc/{id}', [DetailController::class, 'accept']);
function accept($id){
    $users=DB::select('select * from files where id = ?',[$id]);
     return view('accept',['users'=>$users]);
}
```

Comment: Use _either_ a `<button>` element _or_ an `<a href>` element. Don't place `<a>` inside a `<button>`

Comment: can i put the button inside a form and then do it ?

Comment: Button inside a form is ok, adding Javascript to a button to trigger something is also ok. Just using `<a>` is also ok. The thing with `<a>` inside `<button>` is that your click will trigger the `<button>`, not `<a>`

Comment: <form action='onc/{{$users[0]->id}}' method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button class ="accept">Accept</button>
    </form> - even then am getting 404 error

Comment: From your title: "_http://localhost:8000/acce/onc/1 404 (Not Found)_" Is `/acce/` your project root. If not, use `<form action='/onc/...` to start from the root of your webserver

Comment: acc is my previous page...

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem of the 'Party Netflix' extension, try uninstalling it. It worked for me. Greetings.